# Wordpress backend for my own frontend

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Until now, I've always found answers for my questions without even asking them on stack overflow, but in this case I need you assistance.

I hope that you will not find this question to silly.
I'm a pure frontend-focused. I work with html/sass/React/Redux, and I design UI. I've no experience and knowledge in any of backed techniques.

I would like to kick-start some blog. It would just display some posts,  pagination, categories, sharing posts on social media, page "about me"... You all know this stuff. I've clear idea how front-end of this thing will work and I know what approach to designing this I will choose.

I just need some kind of back-end to support me with possibility of doing some AJAX calls for posts. I do not need comments, server side rendering etc. I just would like to create **my own front-end html + css + js application that will get my posts from server and display it in way I want.**

Ok, so I know about Wordpress. Ages ago, I did few sites with it (you gotta make your living somehow), using free templates. I just added some background, changed options and gave my "client" password and login, so they could post some things. that was working just OK.

But now is the thing. I don't want to use any Wordpress template at all. I just need Wordpress interface for posting/managing Posts, and "AJAX get" to fetch the posts. Rest is done with my own front-end that is not concern right now. what should I start with? I do not expect clear answer, just I need someone to point me if this is even possible, or should I think about other approach. **I would like to avoid inventing a wheel once again from scratch.**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382639/recommended-database-backend-for-blog/3382670#3382670) I found this:

> My first recommendation is to use existing software, like WordPress. In that case, you'll want to use their backend, which is going to be a relational database.

This would just be great.

EDIT:

So I found also this:
https://snipcart.com/blog/reactjs-wordpress-rest-api-example

What is your opinion on such approach?

Comment: Use Wordpress in build REST API is right choice.

Comment: Ok, so I made today a deep dive into WP Rest decoupled API and it is looking just great for what I need to do. What is more, I already see it as a good substitute for php background for various applications.

There is also decent resource on this subject:
https://dev.to/jchiatt/headless-wordpress-with-react